# makeValid() error sql geospatial

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, geospatial

I'm writing a project in C# where i use ADO.NET to connect to my SQL Server 2012 database. My database (among other things ) has two columns. the first column represent latitude of a point and the second one represents the longitude. I use a procedure that check if two rectangles on the map intercept each the other. The column reply returns 1 value that is either 0 or 1.
edit: in this example i run it only with numbers, i plan to add variables later
my procedure works fine if i run it on SQL query. But drops error if i run using ADO.net

as SQL query procedure is :

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
DECLARE @s geography;

SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((39.692 23.483, 23.483 39.671, 24.095 39.493, 23.466 39.800,39.692 23.483))', 4326);

SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((39.800096 23.296509, 39.628961 23.128967,39.43195 23.510742 ,39.7093 23.859558,39.800096 23.296509))', 4326);
SET @h =@h.MakeValid();
SET @g = @g.MakeValid();
SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h) as reply
```

/*==============================================================================================================

//------------------------ AS ADO.NET procedure is : -------------------------------

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AGIS-PC;Initial Catalog=ship_maps;Integrated Security=True");// create a connection object


String commandString = @"DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
DECLARE @s geography;
SET @h =@h.MakeValid();
SET @g = @g.MakeValid();
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((39.692 23.483, 23.483 39.671, 24.095 39.493, 23.466 39.800,39.692 23.483))', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((39.800096 23.296509, 39.628961 23.128967,39.43195 23.510742 ,39.7093 23.859558,39.800096 23.296509))', 4326);
SET @h =@h.MakeValid();
SET @g = @g.MakeValid();
SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h) as reply";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn);

try
{
// open the connection
conn.Open();
// 1. get an instance of the SqlDataReader
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
// get the results of each column
string vessel_name = (string)rdr["reply"];
TextBox1.Text += " " + vessel_name;

// .....
}//while
}
finally
{
//...........
}
```

//=========================================================
he error is something with makevalid() i guess. I had similar error in the initial query at sql , then i insert makevalid() and it worked.
edit : it occurs at rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

```
Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.
System.ArgumentException:
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
.
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLArgumentException: 24205: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance because it exceeds a single hemisphere. Each geography instance must fit inside a single hemisphere. A common reason for this error is that a polygon has the wrong ring orientation. To create a larger than hemisphere geography instance, upgrade the version of SQL Server and change the database compatibility level to at least 110.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLArgumentException:
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticIsValid(GeoData& g, Double eccentricity, Boolean forceKatmai)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.IsValidExpensive(Boolean forceKatmai)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2084358
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5096328
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2294
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +86
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +311
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +89
gmaps.Button11_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +185
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

please advise, or if this is for another topic tell me. I'm a beginner with SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code....

1.) You're calling MakeValid() on @g and @h when they are uninitialised variables:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;

SET @h = @h.MakeValid();
SET @g = @g.MakeValid();
```

2.) What is @s for? It's never used...

3.) @g is an invalid, self-intersecting polygon. The appropriate valid instance to represent this pointset is MULTIPOLYGON (((23.483 39.671, 39.692 23.483, 23.721 39.602, 23.483 39.671)), ((23.466 39.8, 23.721 39.602, 24.095 39.493, 23.466 39.8)))

4.) @h has the incorrect ring orientation (that is, assuming that you're not trying to create a Polygon that covers 99% of the earth's surface). It should be POLYGON((39.43195 23.510742, 39.628961 23.128967, 39.800096 23.296509, 39.7093 23.859558, 39.43195 23.510742))

So, your SQL query should be:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((23.483 39.671, 39.692 23.483, 23.721 39.602, 23.483 39.671)), ((23.466 39.8, 23.721 39.602, 24.095 39.493, 23.466 39.8)))', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((39.43195 23.510742, 39.628961 23.128967, 39.800096 23.296509, 39.7093 23.859558, 39.43195 23.510742))', 4326);
SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h) as reply;
```

Which gives the result '1', as represented in SQL Server Spatial Results tab shown below:

[image]

[Pro Spatial with SQL Server 2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234911)